# Removing quotes from a text file in python

Tags: text, python-3.x

I have to remove quotes from a relatively large text file. I have looked at the questions that may have matched this one, yet I am still not able to remove the quotes from specific lines from the text file.

This is what a short segment from the file looks like:

```
1 - "C1".

E #1 - "C1".

2 - "C2".

1

2

E #2 - "C2".
```

I would like to have `1-"C1"`. be replaced by `c1`, and `E #1 - "C1"` be replaced with `E c1`. I tried replacing these in python, but I get an error because of the double `"'s`.

I tried:

```
input=open('file.text', 'r')
output=open(newfile.txt','w')
clean==input.read().replace("1 - "C1".","c1").replace("E #1 - "C1"."," E c1")
output.write(clean)
```

I have with sed:

```
sed 's\"//g'<'newfile.txt'>'outfile.txt'.
```

But yet another syntax error.

Comment: I first tried something I learned from my other question posted today.

Comment: Which is input=open('file.text', 'r')

Comment: Sorry this comment box is flipping out on me

Comment: output=open(newfile.txt','w')

Comment: clean==input.read().replace("1 - "C1".","c1").replace("E #1 - "C1"."," E c1")

Comment: I'd recommend you to delete your comments, and move the information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure you want **literal** replacement, you just need to escape the quotes or use single quotes: `replace('1 - "C1".', "c1")` and so on (and to correct a couple of syntax-breaking typos). This, however, will only work on the first line, so there's no point in reading the whole file then. To do a smarter job, you could use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
with open('file.text') as input, open('newfile.txt','w') as output:
     for line in input:
         line = re.sub(r'^(?P<num>\d+) - "C(?P=num)".$',
                       lambda m: 'c' + m.groups()[0], line)
         line = re.sub(r'^E #(?P<num>\d+) - "C(?P=num)".$',
                       lambda m: 'E c' + m.groups()[0], line)
         output.write(line)
```

In the `sed` command you seem to try to simply remove the quotes:

```
sed 's/"//g' newfile.txt > outfile.txt
```